# Github actions - Writing to GITHUB_ENV from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, github-actions

I currently have a javascript script that i run from within a workflow, which sets an environment variable in this way:

**script.js**

```
console.log(`::set-output name=comment::${comment}`);
```

Github has put a notice that they will be deprecating the usage of `set-output` [here](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/)

In my `.yml` workflow files themselves it's easy enough to replace:

```
echo "::set-output name=comment::true"
```

with

```
echo "commit=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

I am finding it harder to replace the instances in javascript files, because I cannot `>>` it to the `GITHUB_ENV` file.  What would be the preferred way to accomplish this?  I have already accomplished it with the below but would have to modify the return value of my script to do so, and would like to avoid this:

**workflow.yml**

```
COMMENT = yarn my-script
echo "COMMENT=$COMMENT" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

As I mentioned, I would like to accomplish setting the environment variable to `GITHUB_ENV` without having to modify the return type for the script.

Comment: Are you using `actions/toolkit` in your JS action?

Answer (score 3):

For JavaScript, use https://github.com/actions/toolkit.

See [Using workflow commands to access toolkit functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#using-workflow-commands-to-access-toolkit-functions) for more details.

Check `core.exportVariable`, `core.setOutput`, etc. according to your use case.

---

For GHA Workflows, see

- [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) (`GITHUB_ENV`)
- [Setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) (`GITHUB_OUTPUT`)

There are multiple threads on SO to set these according to the runner OS shell.